# jquery wrap found string inside of a span?

Tags: jquery

How do I look inside of all `h3`'s for a specific string like "New" and wrap that inside of a

```
<span class="red">New </span>
```

Comment: You mean something like `<h3><span class="red">New</span></h3>`?

Comment: exactly. I had a hard time finding a solution to search for a string and than wrap it! `<h3><span class="red">New</span>` Some more text</h3>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) to find the word `New` in every `<h3>`, then use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) with a callback to `String.replace()` to apply the `<span>`:

```
$('h3:contains(New)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('New', '<span class="red">New</span>');
});
```

This turns

```
<h3>New stuff</h3>
```

into

```
<h3><span class="red">New</span> stuff</h3>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dt7Ma)

Comment: @Yads: You didn't see that I provided a jsFiddle demo, did you?

Comment: i just saw your earlier version, which didn't have it heh

Comment: @Yads: Ah, fair enough... I'm into that "incremental edit" thing :)