# Change Color of Asterisk inside of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the color of the Asterisk but I can't target the matching character.

Does anyone know how you target the particular text to change it to be red?

My code below changes add the text to be red.

```
$('.highlight').find('*').css('color','#ff0000');
```

Comment: You can't change the color of a text node.  You need to wrap the `*` in a element (such as a `<span>`) and color that.

Comment: The best way to do this is to wrap the asterisk in a pair of `<span>` tags with a special class. You can then add css styles to that span tag, or better yet, add/remove new classes to it as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a lot more complicated than you might think. You'll need to modify your HTML and add some wrapping element like a `<span>`. You could do something like that:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().replace(/\*/g, "<span class=\"asterisk\">*</span>");
    $(this).html(html).find(".asterisk").css("color", "red");
});​
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/akQ75/1/)

Comment: this would not work if you have more than one p element, see: http://jsfiddle.net/akQ75/

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
$('.highlight').each(function(){
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, '<span class="asterisk">*</span>');
});
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/4XrSS/

Answer (score 1):

Put a `span` (or another inline-level element) around it and style the `span`.

JS:

```
var text = $('.highlight').text();
$('.highlight').html(text.replace('*', '<span>*</span>'));
```

CSS:

```
.highlight span {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

**Edit**: oops, find('*') is not working, use `replace`

Comment: I don't think you can use `find` that way.

Comment: `find("*")` does not do what you think it does: it matches all the descendant elements, not the `*` characters in text nodes.

Comment: Be mindful that `replace` will only replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns elements using the specified selector. Since `*` will match all elements, it's basically a no-op. What you are trying to do is selecting part of an element. This is not possible. You have to create a specific element arround the asterisk first.

**Solution:**

You can use a helper method to wrap all `*` in a `span` with a custom class:

```
$('.highlight').each(function() { 
    var regex = new RegExp('\*', 'g'); 

    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="hilite">*</span>'); 
}
```

)

Then you just apply the formatting you want for the `hilite` class.

**Edit:** The code is modified from here [Highlight a word with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119441/highlight-a-word-with-jquery) there are also some more suggestions which might help.

**Edit2:** added suggestions from comment & explanation above

Comment: You know you could also pass your `hilite` function directly and use `$(this)` directly inside to save a function call.

Comment: `hilite($(this));` should be  `hilite(this);`.

Comment: @aKzenT Well you've implemented my suggestion, but the problem that Rocket pointed out is still there. `$(this)` will give you the jQuery object, but you're using native DOM properties (`innerHTML`). So use `this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127408/585552)

CSS:

```
.red { color: red; }​
```

jQuery:

```
$("body :contains('*')").html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('*', '<span class="red">*</span>');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUb3Y/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your finished output is supposed to look like, but might be a fun application of the ":before" css selector and "content" property. You could do something like...

```
.div-with-asterisk:before {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
 }
```

reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp